# How do i add dynamically prepared statments to this PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

In order to achieve different outputs. I would like to use prepared statements so the Select where query will output different records depending on the value of Tags. Since I have just switched to PDO, I am unsure on how to do this.

I have looked into tutorials such as http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php but this shows fixed values to the prepared statments and not values i can change by entering a different URL.

**Current code:**

```
<?php
$pdo=new PDO("mysql:dbname=createyo_TestDatabase;host=localhost","createyo_james","password");
$statement=$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM Articles where Tags = ?");
$statement->execute(array($tag));
$results=$statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$json=json_encode($results);
print $json;
?>
```

Comment: it's just a string. build a string with whatever parameters you need, then bind on-the-fly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add the place holder and pass the array of values to `execute`

```
$statement=$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM Articles where Tags = ?");
$statement->execute(array($tag));
```

Comment: OK. I have added this. How do i construct the URL? I have tried retreiveCustomArticle.php?tag=the

Comment: @jamesgates1 `$statement->execute(array($_GET['tag']));`

Comment: Thank you! 2 days later and I've done it (webhost problems as well) :)